# FaceBook Messenger SDK How to get the user's name

Tags: ios, facebook

I am working on messenger app, mostly by looking at [the docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios)

The only gotcha is how to pass the user information to the person you are sharing the content with?

From docs it seems that `FBSDKMessengerURLHandlerReplyContext` may contain userID

```
NSSet *userIds = context.userIDs
```

Yet, how can i use the userID to get the user information? Or is it even the right way to fetch user info?

It seems like this task is doable. [This game does that](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doodle-draw-for-messenger/id981283701?mt=8)

It can tell the user info in first screen, without actually asking user to login.

Any Idea or help on how to make it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user IDs are from users that already authenticate in your app, it can be achieved using graph API, like they say on facebook Docs:

> User IDs can be used with the Facebook SDK and Graph API
>   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) to query names,
>   photos, and other data. This will only contain IDs of users that have
>   also logged into your app via their Facebook account.

Here some code on how to use the graph API with user id. You can make a call as it follows:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                      initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", {userID-goes-here}]
                                      parameters:@{@"fields":@"name,id,picture,gender,birthday,email"}
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
     if (!error){
          NSLog(@"result: %@",result);           
     }
}];
```

the result of this request looks like this:

```
 {
    birthday = "06/24/1981";
    email = "XXXXXX@hotmail.com";
    gender = male;
    id = 67XXXXX39;
    name = "Adriano Spadoni";
    picture = {
        data = {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
             url = "https://fbcdn-prof... ...jpg";
        };
    };
}
```

Just remember, some fields maybe be null.

You probably will need to do a loop requesting user by user I'm afraid, if someone knows how to ask a patch of users at the same time, please show us how.

**BUT**

If you want to get info from users that NOT installed your app yet, you need to:

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: ["fields":"installed,id,name,picture.width(1000)"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, err) -> Void in
                    if err == nil {
                        print(result)
                    }
                })
```

Comment: AFAIK, with FBMessengerSDK there is no need for authentication. You can just go ahead and share the content. If you see the game link above, you will see that it is getting the user information somehow and does not require app authentication or login.

Comment: I add few more infos, you may do it with "taggeble friends", I just tested and you get the names and pictures =)

Comment: Yes but be carefull with "taggable" friends. It is not supposed to be used this way and Facebook may reject your app is you need their submission later on.

Comment: Getting following error "message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";"
Is there any way to get this token, without user logging into the app ?

Comment: No, the user must loggin to get the Token. Tulleb is right about "taggeble friends" be risk to use.

Comment: Can some one please try the game link that i shared above and guess how they are doing it without asking user to login?

Comment: N0mi, I just install the app and it does not show any friend neither my own name, just  'NAMELESS FOE' with a default black image as thumbnail. You probably connected Facebook. Just delete the app, go to Facebook privacy, remove this app from there and then reinstall it, you see.

Comment: true, only once your friends reply you back, you should be able to see his information. Ok, let me do the steps you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the username anymore because `/me/username` is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

If you want to detect returning users, use the (App Scoped) ID instead.

Comment: Hey Piyush, I almost made the same mistake of think he was asking about "username", but it he said: "user name" (see the space?) he misspelled in the title, it should be "user's name". Thank you for the information anyway, you are right "username" is gone for good on facebook.

Comment: Thanks drix, i fixed the title